# UML Class diagram C++ struct

Tags: c++, uml

How can I show struct members in the UML class diagram. In class diagram, I added struct as attribute and don't know how to add 'x', 'next' elements to that struct. if I generate the C++ from class diagram, it should have 'x' and 'next' elements in struct.

```
 class LinkList
    {
    private:
      // how to show the struct and its members in UML class diagram
      struct node
      {
         int x;
         node *next;
      }*p;

    public:
      // add an element
      void append(int num);

     // counts number of elements
      int count();
    };
```

Comment: Since node is a implementation detail I would omit it from any UML diagram. They can get crowded enough as it is. Generating C++ from UML is just a silly notion.

Answer (score 8):

something like this?!
[image]

and you would just remove the `<<ptr>>` stereotype and use the `*` as well, like `+next:node*`

Comment: Perfect.This is what i am looking for. Could you explain why & what those arrows represent?.

Comment: the noted line is called `Tent`, it's used to specify a type is declared inside another type, here in your case, `node` inside the `LinkedList` class. it's like a cross surrounded with a circle (+), and points to the host(parent) type, also `node` has another reference from itself, same for the `LinkClass` has one. is there anything else should I explain?! I hope I could give some hand :)